# Can't get my form in React to work properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a form where I want to add form rows and edit any row/cell at any time. It seems to work fine by adding new rows but if I edit a previous row/cell the form fields get's messed up.

This is my handleChange for each field:

```
handleChange = (key, e) => {
  const { name, value } = e.target
  const currentRow = this.state.formRows.filter(r => r.key === key)[0]
  const withoutCurrentRow = this.state.formRows.filter(r => r.key !== key)
  const updatedRow = { ...currentRow, [name]: value }
  const newRows = [...withoutCurrentRow, updatedRow]
  this.setState(({ formRows }) => ({ formRows: newRows }))
}
```

Here's my form on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/kmk65kmxno)

Comment: You are updating the row and appending it to last of **newRows**, you have to maintain the **index** of the updated row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing in the arguments in wrong order for one of your inputs. It should be the `key` as first argument and the `event` as second.

```
<Input
  value={description}
  name="description"
  placeholder="description"
  style={{ width: '20%', marginRight: 8 }}
  onChange={e => this.handleChange(key, e)}
/>
<Input
  value={amount}
  name="amount"
  placeholder="amount"
  style={{ width: '20%', marginRight: 8 }}
  onChange={e => this.handleChange(key, e)}
/>
```

You could also use [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to get the index of the object you want to update, and create a new copy of that object in the array with an updated field.

```
handleChange = (key, e) => {
  const { name, value } = e.target;
  this.setState(previousState => {
    const formRows = [...previousState.formRows];
    const currentIndex = formRows.findIndex(row => row.key === key);

    formRows[currentIndex] = { ...formRows[currentIndex], [name]: value };

    return { formRows };
  });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Your solution works well. Just wondering what is the main bug in my code. I'm taking a bit different approach and setting the state after the new one is already created...

Comment: @karolis2017 You're welcome! You filter out the object you want to update and then add it back again at the end of the array. You want to preserve the order of the objects in the array so the inputs don't change order when rendered.

Comment: Got it now. Thanks again

Comment: @karolis2017 Great! Consider upvoting my answer. That would make me happy.